# Word meaning you are describing something as if to a child

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

Looking for a word that describes the feeling of being told something in an overly simplified manner that feels offensive.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Can you update the OP with some examples of how you would like to use this word?

Comment: Not quite the same, but a word that has gained currency of late is [mansplain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/mansplaining-definition-history).

Comment: @HotLicks I think that might be a little too gender specific.

Comment: @Hank - 'Splain it to me.

Comment: @HotLicks The OP just asks for a word to describe talking down to someone. That "word" refers to men, specifically, talking down to someone (usually a woman) about a subject he has no expertise in.

Comment: @Hank - That's why I made it a comment, and said "not quite the same".  Just wanted to make readers of this thread aware of the word (in case they'd been living in a cave the past 5 years).

Comment: @HotLicks I don't want it to seem like I think you shouldn't have commented it. I was just stating an opinion on it :)

Comment: So far, the answers collected aren't really describing the feeling of having been 'splained *to*, which seems to be what the question asks for. Perhaps this means the question needs some clarification.

Answer (score 8):

> ### Patronise
>
> 1. to adopt an air of condescension toward :  treat haughtily or coolly

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronize))

> to behave or treat in a condescending way

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/patronising))

The adjective form of this would be *patronising*.

*A professor who patronises his students* would be someone who acts as if their students are very young.

Answer (score 5):

> ### Condescending
>
> con·de·scend·ing  (kŏn′dĭ-sĕn′dĭng)
>   **adjective**
>
> 1. showing or implying a usually patronizing descent from dignity or superiority:
>      *They resented the older neighbors' condescending cordiality.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/condescending))

This comes from the verb **to condescend**:

> **verb** (used without object)
>
> 1. to behave as if one is conscious of descending from a superior position, rank, or dignity.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/condescend))

Answer (score 2):

The phrase that will work best is:

> ### Talk down to
>
> ***verb***
>
> - **to speak in a condescending or oversimplified fashion**

If you wanted to use a single word, this one may work, depending on the context:

> ### Belittle
>
> ***verb***
>
> - **to cause (a person or thing) to seem little or less; talk down**

Comment: Hi @Hank, these are good words, but can you add a link or reference to your source?

Comment: I like *talk down to.*

Comment: I don't have a computer at home. I'll edit it with the references :)